# Choose connector and Ethernet Transceiver for MCU ethernet interface

Tags: connector, ethernet

I need to add an Ethernet interface to a STM32H745IIT6 MCU. I have to choose the RJ45 connector and the Ethernet transceiver chip.

I state that I've never done this thing, so my idea was to take the Nucleo board schematic and use the same connector and the same chip. The problem is that both the connector and the chip are not available now (unless exorbitant costs), so I would like to select another connector and another chip, but I practically don't know where to start. I don't know what parameters to see and how to choose these components. I need some help.

For the connector, I saw that the Würth catalog is well stocked, and there are also connectors with integrated magnets that would help reduce the BOM. But I don't know which to choose among all these connectors:

https://www.we-online.com/en/components/products/WE-LAN-RJ45

For the Ethernet transceiver chip, I saw that they use an LAN8742A-CZ-TR on the Nucleo board, and I should select an alternative to this chip. Searching the internet there are thousands of alternatives, but I don't know how to figure out which one is suitable for my application (use with an STM32H745IIT6).

Can anyone help me select some parts or can you tell me about the chip + connector already used in other similar applications, and which have no problems.

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you don’t know how to select a similar device, will you have the skills to design the pcb? These are not something you can slap together and hope it will work. As for 1000’s of choices - I don’t think there are that many different 10/100 phy chips. A quick search on Digikey showed slim pickings - there’s a chip shortage and phy chips are scarce.

Comment: If you don’t know how to select a similar device, will you have the skills to design the pcb? -- There's always a first time, I know the first time probably won't work, but I have to start somewhere.

Comment: This is where dev kits can be handy.  Mixing and matching dev kits from various manufacturers is a cheap way to test some of the worse-case scenarios (when it comes to dubious interconnects).  If you can get something to work in those conditions, getting the design translated to your custom PCB should be relatively straight forward.